# Embed multiple view controllers in navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm making an app for iOS based partly on storyboards and programmatically setup. The root view controller (1) is a has a scroll view. In it is two view controllers (2 and 3), and they have further navigation deeper into the app. I want it to be able to make the edge swipe from left to navigate back. When I make the first view controller and "Embed in Navigation Controller" through the Interface Builder, it dosn't enable the back swipe.

Maybe it's because I add view controller 2 and 3 to view controller 1 programmatically? But it dosn't work either if I embed view controller 3 in a navigation controller, eventhoug I have connected everything from there on via segues.

View controller 1, 3 and 5 have scrollviews embedded, maybe the swipe functions of the scrollview overrides the swipe back function?

The view controllers 2 and 3 are embedded in view controller 1 like this:

```
scrollView.addSubview(ViewControllerThree.view)
```

I havn't tried to make the navigation controller programmatically, if that posible.

Any ideas?

[image: Overview of Storyboard]

**EDIT**

I've tried doing it programmatically like this:

I add the following code to app delegate `application_didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, and remove the navigation controller from my storyboard. But I have the same problem, it seems that when I seque away from view controller 2 or 3, I loose the navigation controller.

```
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("New Landing Page")
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    self.window?.rootViewController = nav;
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
```